# Reference element from a ContentView within the ContentView

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

Within my ContentView (name=CvProduct) I have a ListView (nam=LvProducts) and several controls within each cells with their specific commands that are accessible in the Page's (name=Products) viewmodel (name=ProductsViewModel).
I cannot manage to make the bind works.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="Products">
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">
            <views:CvProduct/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </ContentPage.Resources>
</ContentPage>


<ContentView x:Name="CvProduct">
 <xForms:SfListView x:Name="LvProducts">
  <xForms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <forms:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
     <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ConsultElement,
 Source={x:Reference Name=LvProducts}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
    </forms:SvgCachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </xForms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
 </xForms:SfListView>
</ContentView>
```

which always returns this error :

> Message = "Position xyz Can not find the object referenced by `LvProducts`"

Comment: There is CvProduct view, having Listview LvProduct. The above code is in CvProduct view?

Comment: Well, this is a clickable image inside a cell of the ListView. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: the above code is in CvProduct view?

Comment: @CherryBu What do you mean? These are two different Xaml files. One is Products.xaml which is the ContentPage, the other one is the ContentView CvProduct.xaml. I just simplified the code for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference a command `MyCommand` in the binding context of a page named `myPage`:

```
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=myPage}, 
                  Path=BindingContext.MyCommand}"
```

Reference a command `MyCommand` in the binding context of a layout named `myLayout` containing a ListView:

```
Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=myLayout}, 
                  Path=BindingContext.MyCommand}"
```